# Finding specific elements in a list

Tags: python, list

I am trying to write a code that counts the number of specific colors in a single line of code, so far I have:

```
cars = input('Cars: ')
print('red:', cars.count("red"))
print('blue:', cars.count("blue"))
```

But how do I get it to accept "blueish" or "bluey" as well as "blue"?

Comment: You should mention the acceptable input format from the user. If it is a csv or something.

Answer (score -2):

you can use a structure as followed:

```
a=input('cars:')
if 'blue' in a:
    blue+=1
if 'red' in a:
    red+=1
print(red, blue)
```

the structure reads the user input, then searches for the specific color that also includes the phrases you wanted to be covered like blueish, detecting one, it outputs the correct number